# Linear Trend across Sessions and Timepoints: Which Matlab function?

Tags: multiple-regression, repeated-measures, matlab, multivariate-regression

I would like to test for linear a increase in performance in my training study using MATLAB.
In this study each participant went through 6 training sessions, each session containing 4 time points of a learning a task with 2 conditions. So in total there are 24 (6 by 4) repetitions for each condition and participant.
What I am interested in is to see

1. whether there is a main effect of condition
2. whether there is an increase in performance across all 24 repetitions.
3. whether this increase occurs mainly within or across a blocks.

I would normally do this with a repeated measures Anova in SPSS. This gives me the main effect and gives me a significant difference across repetitions. It also gives me a linear trend term with an F value in a separate output.
However, I do not have access to SPSS at the moment and would like to try this in MATLAB.

I was thinking of using ranova for a repeated measures anova. However, I do not understand how to obtain information on the significance of the linear trend. So instead I was going to try a multivariate regression, where b = mvregress(X,y).
y would be the measurement at each repetition (n by 1) and X would be a n by 48 matrix. n being the subjects, and 48 the dummy variables reflecting the possible combinations of block (6), time point (4) and condition (2) coded as 0 and 1.

I am a bit confused, however, whether this approach is valid, as mvregress is built for multiple dependent variables, but I only have one. Would this still be valid? It also fails to capture the repeated measures aspect.

There is also the function *regress*, which is more correct in that regard, as it is designed for just one dependent variable. However, all examples I could find would use numeric input. So it is unclear how I can define the multiple levels of analysis. Can I just enter dummy / design variables here, too?

Any comment appreciated!

---

So what I do now is to use fitlme with the data in long format. Hope that's correct